# How to read object and convert to json in AWS lambda python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My csv is below. I need to convert into json using AWS lambda using python

```
value,Name,flag
ABC,ab@gmail.com|cd@gmail.com,Y
ABC,de@gmail.com,Y
CDE,ab@gmail.com,N
CDE,cd@gmail.com,N
```

Code is below

```
import boto3
import csv
s3_read = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3_read.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
CSVcontent = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')
CSVfile = csv.reader(CSVcontent)
print('CSVfile', list(CSVfile))
```

My current out is

```
[['value', 'Name', 'flag'], ['ABC', 'ab@gmail.com|cd@gmail.com', 'Y'], ['ABC', 'de@gmail.com', 'Y'], ['CDE', 'ab@gmail.com', 'N'], ['CDE', 'cd@gmail.com', 'N']]
```

- I need to merge all the same keys and same flag
- I need to change all the `|` to different string

Expected out is below

```
[{'value': 'ABC', 'name': ['ab@gmail.com','cd@gmail.com','de@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'Y'},
 {'value': 'CDE', 'name': ['ab@gmail.com','cd@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'N'}]
```

Comment: There's nothing AWS or Lambda specific about this. It's just a basic Python coding question.

Comment: @MarkB , I worte code which is working fine in local system, but when i use obj = s3_read.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
my code is not working

Comment: What should happen if two rows with value=ABC actually have different flag values?

Comment: @sim that detail should have been included in your question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your current data (`list(CSVfile)`) and creating a list of dicts

```
current = [['value', 'Name', 'flag'], ['ABC', 'ab@gmail.com|cd@gmail.com', 'Y'], ['ABC', 'de@gmail.com', 'Y'],
           ['CDE', 'ab@gmail.com', 'N'], ['CDE', 'cd@gmail.com', 'N']]


def handle(k, v):
    if k == 'Name':
        return v.split('|')
    else:
        return v


data = []
for entry in current[1:]:
    data.append({k: handle(k,entry[idx]) for idx, k in enumerate(current[0])})
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'value': 'ABC', 'Name': ['ab@gmail.com', 'cd@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'Y'}, {'value': 'ABC', 'Name': ['de@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'Y'}, {'value': 'CDE', 'Name': ['ab@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'N'}, {'value': 'CDE', 'Name': ['cd@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'N'}]
```

Comment: [{'value': 'ABC', 'name': ['ab@gmail.com','cd@gmail.com','de@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'Y'},
 {'value': 'CDE', 'name': ['ab@gmail.com','cd@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'N'}]

Comment: @sim I do not understand your comment. Can you please explain?

Comment: I see .. the emails... OK. Code was changed

Comment: no its not correct still , please check this one

Comment: 'value': 'ABC', 'name': ['ab@gmail.com','cd@gmail.com','de@gmail.com'], 'flag': 'Y